# C# passing serial to class

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Datalogging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public class ThreadExample
    {

        public static void ThreadJob(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\johnmark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\employee.sqlite;";
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
            //open connection to database
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Select empID from EmployeeList", sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader reader;
                reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();


                //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(definition.buffering, reader.GetValue(0))));
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {
                        mainWindow.SerialWrite('s');
                        Console.WriteLine(Text);
                        //richtextbox1.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text)));
                    }
                }
                sqliteCon.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        //string received_data;
        //Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Port");
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }

            }


        }


        private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)button2.Content == "Connect")
                {
                    string myItem = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (myItem == "Select Port")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Select Port");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serial.PortName = myItem;
                        serial.Open();
                        button2.Content = "Disconnect";
                        textbox2.Text = "Serial Port Opened";
                        serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    serial.Close();
                    button2.Content = "Connect";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        #region Receiving


        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
            definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(definition.buffering);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
        }
        #endregion

        public void WriteSerial(string text)
        {
            serial.Write(text);
        }


    }
}
```

Hi guys. Can anyone help me what went wrong in this code? It is displaying this error: 
Error 2 'Datalogging.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SerialWrite' and no extension method 'SerialWrite' accepting a first argument of type 'Datalogging.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 3 Method name expected

how can I fix that? Please edit the code and post it here as your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method call `mainWindow.SerialWrite('s');` to `mainWindow.WriteSerial('s');` to fit the method name declared here :

```
public void WriteSerial(string text)
```

You inverted both words.

---

For your "Method name expected", I guess it's in `port_DataReceived`. You need to pass a delegate to the thread, but you're not doing it correctly.

Instead of

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
```

(you can't directly pass a method as a parameter, you can only use function pointers) you can use this syntax to pass a delegate :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
```

Please note that `new TreadStart` is redundant, `new Thread(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this));` will do the job.

Comment: oh. sorry. I don't see it. HAHA. thanks now it is fixed. how about this one? Error 2 Method name expected

This error is directed here: Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));

Comment: @iaskyou Edited my answer, without the precise line it's hard to say, but I guess it should be there.